# Как можно закинуть какой-то проект на github.com?

Tags: github

Как можно закинуть какой-то проект на github.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок:

1. Нужно пройти регистрацию.
2. Скачать GIT https://git-scm.com/ и установить его.
3. На сайте GitHub Create a new repository, ввести какое-то название.
4. Скопировать ссылку с созданным репозиторием.
5. Открыть установленный GIT где уже произведен вход.
6. Нажать на - Clone a repository.
7. Вставить туда ту ссылку, которую скопировали с www.github.com, указать папку любую (именно в эту папку и будете закидывать свой проект) имя указывать любое, так как она автоматически создастся !
8. Допустим, создали такую папку C:\Users\User\Desktop\New  - это создалась новая папка на рабочем столе.
9. Копируем в эту папку весь свой проект или отдельные классы или любые файлы, короче то что вы хотите видеть у себя на www.github ...
10. Идете снова в приложение GIT и видите все ваши файлы и папки.
11. Слева внизу есть площадка для ввода текста с дэфолтным текстом (Summary) сюда вводите  git add и нажимаете Commit to master далее сверху нажимаете Publish branch.
12. Идете на www.github.com и обновляете страницу .. проект должен появиться.

Comment: А ещё у гитхаба есть десктопный клиент.

Comment: я же написал Скачать GIT https://git-scm.com/ и установить его - это ж и есть этот клиент.

Comment: Неа, это - сам git. А вот гитхабная прога: https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: git add и нажимаете Commit to master  - это что бы добавить Commit к проекту (изменения)